# reactivating :active on stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've got some convoluted code I'm working with and I need a help on a couple of finishing touches.

I have `:active` set in CSS so that it changes the color of a `div` element to a brighter color when you click on it. Later on in the code, it changes the `div` via JavaScript `.style.backgroundColor`.

I noticed that after this, it no longer honors the `:active` color. I was wondering if there was a way to restore or revert this, so that it always has the `:active` brighter color activated when you click it, even though I manually change its bg color through JavaScript.

General example:

`CSS`:

```
 #div1{ background-color:black; };
 
 #div1:active{ background-color:blue; };
```

JS:

```
 document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundColor="red";
```

The `:active` in the CSS (when clicked basically)no longer turns blue after the JS turns it red. How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas come to mind.

1. Easy but a bit hacky, add `!important` so you have:

```
#div1:active{ background-color:blue!important; };
```

2. Instead of setting CSS directly via JS, instead add a class, like "bg-blue", then you can add a CSS line like:

```
.bg-blue:active { background-color:blue; }
```

Comment: for a bit more context, im making an interative interface, seperated into divs. each dif has a color, when you click it, it turns into a brighter version of that color. my JS flashes a div, simulating the "active" state, and i use the js style.backgroundcolor to change it. so the js is kinda important in that aspect. once the js color change kicks in though, the div thats manually clicked no longer lights up to the brighter color specified in the :active part of the css

Comment: OK... did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Good to hear!

Will you mark the answer as valid by clicking the checkmark next to it?